# Get cypress database query output objects in to variables

Tags: javascript, mysql, cypress, browser-automation

I have a cypress test which has been set up with mysql node module. When I run bellow mentioned test Its giving output as follows.

```
const executeQuery = (query) => {
    cy.task('DBQuery', query).then(function (recordset) {
        var rec = recordset
        cy.log(rec)
    })
}
```

Query:

```
select * 
from Users 
where email = 'sheeranlymited@lymitedtest.com'
```

OUTPUT: log [Object{23}]

Query:

```
select firstname 
from Users 
where email = 'sheeranlymited@lymitedtest.com'
```

OUTPUT: log [{firstname: Edward}]

instead of `cy.log(rec)` I want to get the output of 23 columns to assign in to different variables based on the column name.

[image]

Appreciate if someone can help me to resolve this...

Comment: I have tried "cy.log(rec['firstname'])" but its also not giving any output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.values` in js to retrieve values from your object

Let's say you need to extract the value of the 3rd column, so your code will look like,

```
cy.task('DBQuery', query).then(function (recordset) {
    var rec = recordset
    const results = Object.values(rec[0])
    // results[index of the column] will output the results
    cy.log(results[3])
})
```

We can do a small modification to make your task easier,

```
cy.task('DBQuery', query).then(function (recordset) {
    var rec = recordset
    const Values = Object.values(rec[0]);
    const keys = Object.keys(rec[0]);
    let result = {};
    let index = 0;
    keys.forEach(key => {
        result[keys[index]] = Values[index];
        i++
    })
     //result.firstName will give you your results
     cy.log(result.firstName);
})
```

In this way, we are generating key-value pairs having the key as the column name. So you can use the column name to find the value.

Hope this helps.

cheers.